# How to implement the below OOP patterns in Rust?

Tags: oop, inheritance, rust

After reading the Rust book, I am still wrapping my head around the OOP implementation of the below Python code in Rust:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        
    @abstractmethod
    def eat(self):
        pass
    
class Dog(Animal):
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, favorite_bone):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.favorite_bone=favorite_bone
    
    def eat(self):
        print(f"Eating {self.favorite_bone}")
        
dog = Dog("Tom", 1, "big bone")
dog.eat()
```

The `eat` method could be done with a `trait` that is implemented for `Dog`, but then I want to benefit from the OOP inheritance for the fields `name` and `age` as well. (Note that I am giving a very simple example but the problem at hand in practice has a lot more fields and methods).

So this is what I have done so far:

```
trait Animal {
    fn new(name: String, age: u8) -> Self;
    fn eat(&self);
}

struct Dog {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    favorite_bone: String,
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn new(name: String, age: u8) -> Dog {
        Dog {
            name,
            age,
            favorite_bone: String::new(),
        }
    }

    fn eat(&self) {
        println!("Eating {}", self.favorite_bone);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dog = Dog {
        name: String::from("Tom"),
        age: 1,
        favorite_bone: String::from("big bone"),
    };

    dog.eat();
}
```

My main issue is that for all `struct` that implement the `Animal` trait I will need to redefine the `new` method with a lot of similar logic of setting the `name`, `age` (and in practice way more fields). Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I can't give you the "right" way to translate your code into Rust, because there are several ways to express it depending on what the actual requirements are. You shouldn't try to write OOP in Rust, you should try to solve your problem in Rust. With all that said, you could have something similar if you start with an `Animal` struct and then `struct Dog{ animal: Animal, favorite_bone: String }`. But instead of an `Animal` trait, I'd use an `Eater` trait, because traits don't care about what a thing is, they care about what it can do. If a struct can do several things, create more traits.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to prefer composition to inheritance (not only in Rust).
A struct contains the common parts of the concept to implement and also one (or several) pointer to a dynamic part which can change in the OOP way.
Such a dynamic part is generally a boxed object implementing an interface (a trait in Rust).

In the example below, I decided to make the `.eat()` method mutate the animal in order to illustrate a subtlety.
Indeed, we cannot invoke `self.eating_behaviour.eat(self)` because the parameter is an exclusive reference, although it is used at the beginning of the invocation.
The trick relies on a take/reassign sequence on an option holding the dynamic behaviour.

```rust
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

pub mod abstract_level {

    pub struct Animal {
        name: String,
        weight: u8,
        eating_behaviour: Option<Box<dyn EatingBehaviour>>,
    }
    impl Animal {
        pub fn new(
            name: String,
            weight: u8,
            eating_behaviour: Box<dyn EatingBehaviour>,
        ) -> Self {
            Self {
                name,
                weight,
                eating_behaviour: Some(eating_behaviour),
            }
        }
        pub fn name(&self) -> &str {
            &self.name
        }
        pub fn weight(&self) -> u8 {
            self.weight
        }
        pub fn increase_weight(
            &mut self,
            delta: u8,
        ) {
            self.weight += delta
        }
        pub fn eat(&mut self) {
            // take/reassing in or dor to avoid multiple exclusive refs
            if let Some(eating_behaviour) = self.eating_behaviour.take() {
                eating_behaviour.eat(self);
                self.eating_behaviour = Some(eating_behaviour);
            }
        }
    }

    pub trait EatingBehaviour {
        fn eat(
            &self,
            me: &mut Animal,
        );
    }
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

pub mod dog_specific {
    use super::abstract_level::{Animal, EatingBehaviour};

    struct DogEatingBehaviour {
        favorite_bone: String,
    }
    impl DogEatingBehaviour {
        fn new(favorite_bone: String) -> Self {
            Self { favorite_bone }
        }
    }
    impl EatingBehaviour for DogEatingBehaviour {
        fn eat(
            &self,
            me: &mut Animal,
        ) {
            println!("dog eating {}", self.favorite_bone);
            me.increase_weight(2);
        }
    }

    // for convenience
    pub fn make_dog(
        name: String,
        weight: u8,
        favorite_bone: String,
    ) -> Animal {
        Animal::new(
            name,
            weight,
            Box::new(DogEatingBehaviour::new(favorite_bone)),
        )
    }
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

pub mod cat_specific {
    use super::abstract_level::{Animal, EatingBehaviour};

    struct CatEatingBehaviour {}
    impl CatEatingBehaviour {
        fn new() -> Self {
            Self {}
        }
    }
    impl EatingBehaviour for CatEatingBehaviour {
        fn eat(
            &self,
            me: &mut Animal,
        ) {
            println!("cat eating");
            me.increase_weight(1);
        }
    }

    // for convenience
    pub fn make_cat(
        name: String,
        weight: u8,
    ) -> Animal {
        Animal::new(name, weight, Box::new(CatEatingBehaviour::new()))
    }
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

fn main() {
    let mut animals = [
        dog_specific::make_dog("Tom".to_owned(), 10, "big bone".to_owned()),
        cat_specific::make_cat("Hop".to_owned(), 3),
    ];
    for a in animals.iter_mut() {
        println!("~~~~~~~~");
        println!("{}, {} kg", a.name(), a.weight());
        a.eat();
        println!("{}, {} kg", a.name(), a.weight());
    }
}
/*
~~~~~~~~
Tom, 10 kg
dog eating big bone
Tom, 12 kg
~~~~~~~~
Hop, 3 kg
cat eating
Hop, 4 kg
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can't have inheritance between structs, you can make structs implement same trait. Since your Python code contains two classes, you need two structs and a trait for both, rather than just a trait/struct, as in your implementation.

To benefit from borrowing implementations from a *base* class, you just need to **delegate** instead of **inheriting**.

There are multiple ways to do it and whatever you do, make sure you are in sync with Rust's requirements regarding the lifetime dependencies between the owner instance and the owning instance.

But just to give you an example that would be close to yours Python code:

```
trait Creature {
    fn eat(&self) -> ();
}

struct Animal {
    age: i32
}

impl Animal {
    fn new(age: i32) -> Self {
        Self { age }
    }
}

impl Creature for Animal {
    fn eat(&self) {
        println!("Animal::eats, age: {:?}", self.age );        
    }
}

struct Dog {
    a: Animal,
    bone: i32
}

impl Dog {
    fn new(age: i32, bone: i32) -> Self {
        Self { a: Animal::new(age), bone }
    }
}

impl Creature for Dog {
    fn eat(&self) {
        println!("Dog::eats, age: {:?}, bone: {:?}", self.a.age, self.bone );        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let animal = Animal::new(1);
    animal.eat();

    let dog = Dog::new(1, 6);
    dog.eat();
}
```

Note that the only delegation here is for the data (the `age` is delegated to `a`) but if the `eat` would not just print but rather return something, the delegating struct (`Dog`) could use the instance it delegates the call to, call the method and consume it in its own `eat`.